# How display zero value if there is no value matched in linked tables

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, qsqlquery

As per my below query, How i can get the last row with value "0" if there is no data in "inc" table between the selected dates.

My query:

```
select
    Calls = count(*)
  , Cust = i.Cust_id
  , Contract = c.con_id
  , Serv_Time = sum(Serv_Time)
from inc as i
  inner join contract as c
    on i.item_id = c.item_id
    and i.inc_date >= c.[start]
    and i.inc_date <= c.[end]
where c.[start]>='20160101'
group by i.Cust_id, c.con_id 
order by i.Cust_Id, c.con_id
```

Expected output:

```
+-------+---------+------------+-----------+
| Calls |  Cust   |  Contract  | Serv_Time |
+-------+---------+------------+-----------+
|     1 | Amir    | MS2016     |       300 |
|     2 | John    | HP2016     |       180 |
|     1 | Kerlee  | OR2016     |        40 |
|     1 | Nick    | CIS2016    |       120 |
|     2 | samanta | EMC2016    |       200 |
|     0 | Amir    | MS2016-New |         0 |
+-------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Table structures:

```
create table inc
(
    inc_id int
  , cust_id varchar(16)
  , item_id varchar(16)
  , serv_time int
  , inc_date  date
);

insert into inc values
 (1,'john','HP', 40 ,'17-Apr-2015')
,(2,'John','HP', 60 ,'10-Jan-2016')
,(3,'Nick','Cisco', 120 ,'11-Jan-2016')
,(4,'samanta','EMC', 180 ,'12-Jan-2016')
,(5,'Kerlee','Oracle', 40 ,'13-Jan-2016')
,(6,'Amir','Microsoft', 300 ,'14-Jan-2016')
,(7,'John','HP', 120 ,'15-Jan-2016')
,(8,'samanta','EMC', 20 ,'16-Jan-2016')
,(9,'Kerlee','Oracle', 10 ,'02-Feb-2017');

create table contract (
    item_id varchar(16) 
  , con_id varchar(16)
  , [Start] date
  , [End] date
);
insert into contract values 
 ('Dell','DE2015','20150101','20151231')
,('HP','HP2015','20150101','20151231')
,('Cisco','CIS2016','20160101','20161231')
,('EMC','EMC2016','20160101','20161231')
,('HP','HP2016','20160101','20161231')
,('Oracle','OR2016','20160101','20161231')
,('Microsoft','MS2016','20160101','20161231')
,('Microsoft','MS2016-New','20160101','20161231')
,('Microsoft','MS2017','20170101','20171231');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and function `ISNULL()` to set `NULL` to zero. It would not be a problem get zero value if you can generate the lines (left outer join)

Comment: select  
    ISNULL((count(*)), 0) AS Calls
  , Cust = i.Cust_id
  , Contract = c.con_id
  ,
  ISNULL((sum(Serv_Time)), 0) AS Serv_Time
from inc as i
  left outer join contract as c
    on i.item_id = c.item_id
    and i.inc_date >= c.[start]
    and i.inc_date <= c.[end]
where c.[start]>='20160101'
group by i.Cust_id, c.con_id 
order by i.Cust_Id, c.con_id